# Call to a member function toBase() on array

Tags: laravel, resources

I am trying to use resource collection and I am receiving this error " Call to a member function toBase() on array"

> The following code is in my resource :

```
class dataCollection extends ResourceCollection
{

    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'data' => $this->collection
        ];
    }
}
```

> and here is code from the controller:

```
        $projects = count(Project::all());
    $services = count(Service::all());
    $users = count(User::all());
    $technologies = count(Technology::all());
    $customers = count(Customer::all());
    $data = [
        'projects' => $projects,
        'services' => $services,
        'users' => $users,
        'technologies' => $technologies,
        'customers' => $customers
    ];
    return new dataCollection($data);
```

> > Can someone help me please?

Comment: It would be more helpful if you posted the code that involves the error.  Where is `toBase()` called, what is it, and where do you call `toArray()`?

Comment: that is the problem that I am not using `toBase()` and in my Postman is written "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to a member function toBase() on array in file /home/ion/dots/dots-backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Resources/CollectsResources.php on line 26"

Comment: I see. What does DataCollection look like (model?) and when do you use toArray() ? can you show the DataCollection model fields or migration please?  IE how are you using the resource collection?  If Something::collection(collection), do you actually have a collection, or just an array (`$data`)?

Comment: I edited my post and I put there my resource and this is the full code that I use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your end goal is, but it appears the problem is that, as the error says, you are sending the wrong type of data into a collection.  The resource collection method in this case is looking for a set of objects, and you are sending an array.

[By the manual](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources#resource-collections), its looking for something like this with a collection of **User** *objects*:

```
UserResource::collection(User::all());  // User collection, not the raw data array
```

If you are trying to send data back to someone via some API or json, I think you already have what you need - perhaps skip the whole resource collection method if you can?  So try this:

```
$data = [
    'projects' => Project::count(),
    'services' => Service::count(),
    'users' => User::count(),
    'technologies' => Technology::count(),
    'customers' => Customer::count()
];

return json_encode($data);
```

Note I changed the code a little to make it more efficient for you - you don't need to assign into variables first - and by calling `::all()` plus `count()`, it is going to make much heavier database queries

The `toArray()` method on the resource would actually re-convert objects into the type of array you have above - so I suggest you test by skipping the circular process.